# Gaussview GMMX grid seach: job completed before going through all the structures

Tags: computational-chemistry, conformers, molecular-mechanics

I am recently using the GMMX add-on in gaussview to conduct conformer search. I was using the grid search method and the progrom suggested the number of structures is 729 (See picture below). I submitted the job and it completed normally. However when I checked the log file, the "Nmin" is 496 (See picture below). I think "Nmin" should indicate the number of times of minimizations. So what I am confused about is why it is not 729?

If it's some built-in algorithms to skipping some structures, I got even smaller Nmin when I was using smaller bond resolution.

Thanks!

[image: my GMMX setting]

[image: last three lines of the gmmx-log file]

Comment: I am not familiar with GMMX, but two things come to my mind: 1. Does increasing the energy window (eg. To 100 kcal/mol) include other structures? 2. Could some structures be excluded because of symmetry (and hence redundancy?)

Comment: This question may fit on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/)